# Movie with aliens that looked like rocks and would eat people's faces

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, horror

I saw a movie when I was a child; I was born in '73.

These aliens looked like rocks and lured people in and would eat people's faces when they got too close to them. I believe the rocks were blue.

There was one specific scene, closer to the end I think, and there was a guy on the beach who saw one of these rocks and walked up and looked into it and he was pulled in and the rock ate his face.

It's been so long and I checked *Night of the Comet*, and *The Monolith Monsters* (that was black and white, mine was in color) and the people were not in space suits; it was Earth.

Anyone?

Comment: Thank you @LogicDictates for editing my post to be more precise.

Comment: Appropriate Muppets: [Vendaface](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeS8FqupspQ)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pre-80s movie with an alien monster who looks like a rock](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4499/pre-80s-movie-with-an-alien-monster-who-looks-like-a-rock)

Comment: @shoover - [our policy for story-id duplicates](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7067/39144) is to only close when _both_ questions have an accepted answer

Comment: @shoover unfortunately no. That question on the board is actually what led me to this site. I searched all the answers to that post, and that was why I mentioned in the post that they were not in space suits, that this took place on Earth. Thank you for trying though!